# Updating a value in a Hash of an array or hashes

Tags: perl, hashmap

I am initializing a hash table like so:-

```
my %AllCountStats = ();
foreach my $Log (@LogList) {
    foreach my $Func (keys %AllFuncNames) {
        push @{$AllCountStats{$Log}}, {Func=>$Func,Count=>0};
    }
}
print Dumper (\%AllCountStats);
```

The Dumper output looks like this:-

```
$VAR1 = {
    'log.1' => [
        {
            'Count' => 0,
            'Func' => 'Function A'
        },
        {
            'Func' => 'Function B',
            'Count' => 0
        },
    }
    'log.2' => [
        {
            'Count' => 0,
            'Func' => 'Function A'
        },
        {
            'Count' => 0,
            'Func' => 'Function X'
        },
    };
```

Now I need to iterate through a hash of an array of hashes and surgically update the Count values for each Func. Using the above example, what command do I issue to update log.1's Func=Function A value of Count to something new (i.e. not 0)? Here is an example of where/how I am trying to make the update...

```
foreach $Log (@LogList) {
    foreach (sort {$a->{SCmdLineNum} <=> $b->{SCmdLineNum}} @{$SweepStats{$Log}}) {
        $SCmd = $_->{SCmd};
        my $inner = $AllCountStats{$Log}{$SCmd}{Count};
        $inner->{$_}++ for keys %$inner;
    }
}
```

But it is not working. When $inner effectively becomes $AllCountStats{log.1}{Function B}{Count}, how can I cleanly updates its Count value?

Comment: Where do `%SweepStats` come from? Please try to edit the code so we can run it and reproduce your problem. What do you mean by "not working"?

Comment: Hi, @choroba, you don't really need to concern yourself with %SweepStats--the main question is how to surgically update the Count fields in %AllCountStats. When I try to issue that $inner->{$_}++, it reports that the previous line is an illegal hash reference, so I assume it is formatted incorrectly.

Comment: Re "*you don't really need to concern yourself with %SweepStats*", ok, true, but we do need to know which `Count` you're trying to increment for a given element of `@{$SweepStats{$Log}}`.

Comment: Tip: That `sort` is useless. Nothing in the loop cares about the order in which the elements are visited.

Answer (score 2):

`$AllCountStats{$Log}` is a reference to an array, but you treat it as a reference to a hash.

This

```perl
$AllCountStats{$Log}{$SCmd}{Count}
```

should be

```perl
$AllCountStats{$Log}[$i]{Count}
```

It's unclear what value you want for `$i`. We'll come back to that.

---

Next, the following makes no sense:

```perl
my $inner = $AllCountStats{$Log}[$i]{Count};
$inner->{$_}++ for keys %$inner;
```

`$inner` is just a number, not a hash reference. You want

```perl
my $inner = $AllCountStats{$Log}[$i]
++$inner->{Count};
```

or just

```perl
++$AllCountStats{$Log}[$i]{Count};
```

---

Back to `$i`. My best guess is that you want to increment the `Count` of the record which has a `Function` value equal to `$SCmd`.

```
for my $log_name (@LogList) {
   my $log = $AllCountStats{$log_name};

   for my $stats_rec (@{$SweepStats{$Log}}) {  # Useless sort removed.
      my $SCmd = $stats_rec->{SCmd};
      for my $log_rec (@$log) {
         ++$log_rec->{Count} if $log_rec->{Function} eq $SCmd;
      }
   }
}
```

If that's the case, it would be simpler if you build `%AllCountStats` so it looks like

```perl
my %AllCountStats = (
   'log.1' => {
       'Function A' => 0,
       'Function B' => 0,
   },
   ...
);
```

Then, all you'd need is

```
for my $log_name (@LogList) {
   my $log = $AllCountStats{$log_name};
   for my $stats_rec (@{$SweepStats{$Log}}) {
      ++$log->{ $stats_rec->{SCmd} };
   }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion! Your assumptions are spot-on and your recommendation worked. I apologize for not having a cleaner original post, but it was painful to extract out the essence of the issue (many complex logs, proprietary details, thousands of functions, etc., but only Count needed to be modified).

Answer (score 1):

Please see the following piece of code (should be easy to understand)

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $log   = 'log.1';
my $func  = 'Function A';
my $count = 5;

my %AllCountStats = (
    'log.1' => [
        {
            'Count' => 0,
            'Func' => 'Function A'
        },
        {
            'Func' => 'Function B',
            'Count' => 0
        }
    ],
    'log.2' => [
        {
            'Count' => 0,
            'Func' => 'Function A'
        },
        {
            'Count' => 0,
            'Func' => 'Function X'
        }
    ]
);

for ( @{$AllCountStats{$log}} ) {
    $_->{'Count'} = $count if $_->{'Func'} eq $func;
}

say Dumper(\%AllCountStats);
```

Comment: @'Polar Bear' thanks so much--this is exactly what I needed to do, and it is working just right!

Answer (score 0):

The second level of the structure seems to be an array, not a hash. You need square brackets for it.

In `%AllCountStats`, you store numbers under the key "Count". This number is stored in `$inner`, and you then try to dereference it as a hash.

Increment the value directly instead:

```
++$AllCountStats{$Log}[$SCmd]{Count}
```

Comment: (I doubt `$SCmd` is a number. I think there's more to it than this)

Comment: Correct $SCmd is actually a complicated text string--need to use index() != -1 to validate matches, etc.

Comment: Then I don't understand how you want to use a complicated text string to index into an array.